# Hazelcast Jet vs Java 8 streams

Tags: java, hazelcast-jet

I'm trying sort `List<Map<String,Object>>` object based on max date using Hazelcast Jet.

Here is my java 8 code that works:

```
public static List<Map<String, Object>> extractDate1(List<Map<String, Object>> data) {
    return data.stream().map(value -> new Object() {
        Map<String, Object> theMap = value;
        LocalDate date = extractDate(value);
    }).sorted(Comparator.comparing(obj -> obj.date)).map(obj -> obj.theMap).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static LocalDate extractDate(Map<String, Object> value) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MM-yyyy");
    return LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.parse(value.get("effectiveDate").toString(), formatter2).format(formatter1),
            formatter);
}
```

The above java 8 code sorts the map objects from low to high:

Below is the `Jet` code that I'm trying to extract also giving proper output. But I just want to make use of hazelcast jet aggregate/rolling functions

```
// fetching jsonb type data from db
BatchStage<Object> jobJson = dbValue
        // this model holds the string json value
        // converting json data to Map object
        .map(model -> JsonUtil.mapFrom(model.getJosnValue())
    .filter(map -> map.size() != 0)
    .map(map -> {
            // each json/map object will be having an array and again an array will I have multiple json objects in the
            // I'm filtering json objects based on max date 
      List<Map<String, Object>> extractedDateValue;
            if (map.containsKey("records")) {
         //Here I'm calling external function (above java 8 code)
                 extractedDateValue = extractMapBasedOnMax(
                        (List<Map<String, Object>>) map.get("records"));
            }
                
            return extractedDateValue.get(extractedDateValue.size() - 1);
        });
```

JSON data example:

```json
{
    "id": "01",
    "records": [{
        "location": "xyz1",
        "effectiveDate": "02-03-2021"
    }, {
        "location": "xyz2",
        "effectiveDate": "02-04-2021"
    }]
}
```

Expeceted Output:

```json
{
  "location": "xyz2",
   "effectiveDate": "02-04-2021"
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this through Hazelcast Jet rolling aggregations? Or any suggestions would be helpful.. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use rolling aggregation to find a single max element? With rolling aggregation you can, for example, for each input item emit the max item observed so far.

Comment: The approach that I'm using Is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [flatMapping](https://jet-start.sh/docs/api/stateless-transforms#flatmap) the pipeline and finding the maximum using [topN](https://jet-start.sh/docs/api/stateful-transforms#aggregate). flatMap would convert each JSON structure to series of [id, location, effectiveDate] records. See the documentation of [flatMap](https://jet-start.sh/docs/api/stateless-transforms#flatmap) for code sample.

It's not clear whether you want to find max element in the whole collection or max element per id. Adding a [groupingKey](https://jet-start.sh/docs/api/stateful-transforms#groupingkey) would find maximum per id.

The pipeline shape in a "metacode":

```
source // stream of JSON structures
.flatMap // stream [id, location, effectiveDate]
.groupingKey // for maximum per id, remove for global max
.aggregate(AggregateOpperations.topN) // finds max 
.sink;
```